# System.Xml.Linq.XElement System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElement method not found on MSBuild shipped with docker image

Tags: .net, docker, msbuild

When I try to dockerize my app, it got this error

```
/root/.nuget/packages/msbump/2.3.2/build/MSBump.targets(6,5): error : Method not found: 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElement(System.Xml.Linq.XNode, System.String, System.Xml.IXmlNamespaceResolver)'
```

From googling around, [I found that this was caused by MSBuild that wasnt shipped with Visual Studio doesnt have the extension](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-68273/Build-Failing-MSBumpBeforeBuild-error-Method-not-found). And true that I could reproduce it by using MSBuild that shipped with Jetbrains Rider instead of Visual Studio.

The issue is that I want to build the app using docker, and MSBuild on the image that I use mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0, seems to not have the extension. Is there any way to install the extension to MSBuild?

Thanks

I've tried to add the extension using Nuget to the project file but it also doesnt seems to works.

Comment: [MSBump](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBump) is a third party NuGet package. It is not part of MSBuild and does not ship with MSBuild. You should be able to add a `PackageReference` to your project. How are you adding the package to the project? Are you running a `restore`?

Comment: yes, I did `restore` the project but still failed. I think the problem is not that `MSBuild` doesnt have `MSBump`, its `System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElement` that was not shipped with `MSBuild`.

Comment: btw, if we call `msbuild -v` on both machines with VS and docker, it return version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET Framework and version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET. So its seems there's differences between `.NET Framework` and just `.Net`. Wonder if we could use `.NET Framework` on docker.

Comment: In the docker image, are you actually using `dotnet msbuild -v`? The standalone msbuild executable is not installed with the .NET SDK.

Comment: yes, I run `dotnet msbuild -v` on the container build from `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0`. I think `dotnet/sdk` image have all the build tools, while image like `dotnet/aspnet` or `dotnet/runtime` are the one that dont have build tools.